# How have I misconfigured basic auth for my wordpress site?

Tags: htaccess

I've installed Wordpress on a bare Ubuntu20-04 box following [Digital Ocean's guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-a-lamp-stack).
Now I want to password protect the entire site but as I can't find any plugins that protect uploaded files and images, I'm attempting to use basic auth.

So I've created a .htpasswd file

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 132 Jan 12 00:07 /etc/wordpress/.htpasswd
```

I've edited /var/www/mysite.com/.htaccess (substituting a real domain for mysite)
to read:

```
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /etc/wordpress/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

But the site still loads happily without my desired ugly login prompts.
**...what am I doing wrong?**

Alternative solutions to basic auth are welcome but I thought that appeared to be the simplest route to protecting uploaded content. (it's for hosting info about an apartment block for the block's inmates and some things eg meeting minutes are semi-confidential - if people have to log in once per session to access the site I don't mind)

Comment: Is `.htaccess` otherwise being processed? Do you have "pretty" permalinks? What is `AllowOverride` set to in the vHost for you site?

Comment: I had ```
<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all granted
</Directory>``` in my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
which is presumably where i was going wrong?

Comment: (Use single backticks for inline code in comments.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok editing the default-ssl.conf as described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04) (or in my case /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com-le-ssl.conf) to add auth settings to the end of the Virtual Host block **works fine now**.
So it's now:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem
    <Directory "/var/www/mysite.com">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Area"
        AuthUserFile /etc/wordpress/.htpasswd
        require valid-user
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The page also explains how to use .htaccess files by modifying AllowOverride.

I should probably comment on the [guide I originally followed](https://www.zigpress.com/password-protecting-an-entire-wordpress-site/)

Comment: Is this an answer or additional information?!

Comment: It's intended as an answer - it seems to solve my problem. - but I can't accept it as an answer yet - and I'd welcome any better suggestions - such as your question about what my AllowOverride settings are.

Comment: Ok, but that would seem to imply that your `.htaccess` file (and the contained mod-rewrite / WordPress front-controller) is not being used? Are you not using WordPress "pretty" permalinks?

Answer (score 1):

> I had `<Directory /var/www/> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks AllowOverride None Require all granted </Directory>` in my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` which is presumably where i was going wrong?

If that is the only place where `AllowOverride` was defined then that would certainly be the problem. However, that would also mean that your `.htaccess` file was not being processed at all and you are not using WordPress permalinks.

However, that `AllowOverride None` directive covering the *parent* `/var/www/` directory is not necessarily incorrect if you have an overriding `AllowOverride All` (or similar) directive that covers the `/var/www/mysite.com/` directory in the relevant `<VirtualHost>` container - this would be the more usual configuration. You deny access for the parent directory and allow access for specific subdirectories.

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite.com/>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`Options -Indexes` disables directory listings (mod_autoindex), which is enabled in the parent config.

Comment: Thanks... that points me at my issue /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com.conf
contained `<Directory /var/www/wordpress/> AllowOverride All </Directory>`
 not /var/www/mysite.com/ ... sigh - a cut and paste from the tutorial error.
I'll check the Options -Indexes directive now thanks